# How can I remove the dependency of having a `vimfiles` folder in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, vim, vimrc

On `linux` I can put my `colors`/`syntax`/`bundle` folder right into `.vim` which doesnt seem to work on windows, it forces me to put them into a subdirectory called `vimfiles`.

Ill try to visualize what I want to achieve, that is my current folder structure for vim on windows:

```
vim
|-- vim74
|   |-- vim.exe
|   `-- etc
`-- vimfiles
    |-- colors
    `-- etc
```

The structure that I use on linux, how do I make that work on windows?

```
vim
|-- vim74 (this folder doesnt exist on linux ;))
|   |-- vim.exe
|   `-- etc
|-- colors
`-- etc
```

**Why does vim expect a different folder structure on windows?**

Comment: Why is that important? Whether it's `$HOME/vimfiles/` or `$HOME/.vim/` doesn't change *anything*.

Comment: I could snychronize the files between linux and windows more easily

Comment: No, the name of the root directory of your git repo doesn't matter.

Comment: the problem is that on windows my `colors` / etc directories are in another subdirectoy that needs to be called `vimfiles` while on linux they arent (they are right in the root directory there). Its not about naming the root directory

Comment: **You are doing your configuration in the wrong place on *both* systems.** Use `$HOME/vimfiles/` on Windows and `$HOME/.vim/` on Linux.

Comment: No im in the right place on linux for sure, but yes in windows im not doing it under `$HOME/vimfiles` because I would like to run it from a thumb drive

Comment: Another option which requires no vim config changes is to create a set of symlinks, named and relatively located in a way that lends itself to easy copying between oses. In other words leave viminfo paths, vimrc loc etc as is and use mklink to map these files to another part of the hard drive and name / locate them as you'd like. Little bit of setup time but it might result in a workable solution ( granted its a little out of left field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does not hide files and folders with names containing a leading dot.  I can't recall why the decision was made to make the user-runtime directory `vimfiles` under Windows, but it was.

Without knowing why you want to change that dependency (I'm assuming you mean change and not remove), I can only tell you that you will have to modify the 'runtimepath' option.  Either just add your own preferred directories:

```
:set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
```

Or do the above, *and* remove the default user-runtime directory:

```
:set runtimepath-=~/vimfiles runtimepath-=~/vimfiles/after
```

See:

```
:help 'runtimepath'
```

Comment: I would like to not use the `vimfiles` dir so that I can easily sync between linux and windows. `~/` on windows evaluates to the user profile directory right?

Comment: Yes, Vim expands ~ sanely in Unix or Windows.

Comment: How would I modify my runtimepath so that I can have my `bundle` dir in the same directory as `vim74` (so the vim root directory I guess)

Comment: :help $VIMRUNTIME -- Vim should expand that variable for you in the 'runtimepath' option.

Comment: I read the help file, and what I want is that vim searches the `$VIM` dir for `colors` / `bundle` / etc (like it does in linux, for me at least). Is that possible in windows? Isnt `$VIM` allready in the rtp string?

Comment: I haven't done anything with bundle directories, but as far as I know if it works on Linux, it should work the same on Windows.

Comment: Well I tried `rtp+=$VIM` and put my `colors` directory into `$VIM`, but it didnt work. It only works in windows if the `colors` dir is in `$VIM/vimfiles`. (Sorry I should have said I use `pathogen` which uses a directory called `bundle` to store the plugins in

Comment: It works for me now if I just add `set rtp+=$VIM/` for a portable installation on a stick or `set rtp+=$HOME` for a regular installation. It will remove the need to have a `vimfiles` folder on windows so vim follows the exact same folder structure as on linux (both the `.vimrc` and `autoload`/`colors`/... in the same directory)

Answer (score 0):

Use `%HOMEPATH%/viminfo` or `~/.vim`, which obviously contain the `_vimrc` or `.vimrc` (Windows vs Linux for both) is built into the (g)vim executable. The only options that I am aware of to move them are:

1. Add the the path to `vimrc` as an argument to the executable:

   ```
   gvim.exe -u c:/path/to/your/viminfo/_vimrc
   ```

   Inside that `_vimrc` add a line to instruct vim that your `viminfo` folder is not in the default location:

   ```
   set viminfo=c:/path/to/your/viminfo   
   (alternatively use += to not overwrite)
   ```

   Vim will now look in that directory for your plugins and other support files.
2. Do #1, but in a batch file so you can have a shortcut to it.
3. Vim will load, on windows, the `_vimrc` that is colocated with the executable. Modify that to change the location of your `vimrc` and set the viminfo path. Note that this is a bad idea on a multi-user machine.
4. Rebuild vim from source on windows; changing where this is set in the source code. This isn't actually very hard, assuming you have some experience in building software.

I'm sure there are other options.

Comment: I just googled viminfo and it doesnt seem like it is what im searching for, but maybe I didnt understand it correctly

Comment: As a general rule you shouldn't modify a programs installation directly. vim supports overriding those directories by sourcing those found in your viminfo directory last. If you change the hard coded viminfo path using any of these methods, you can put these other folders there, and not worry about the structure in the installation directory.  You said the vim executable was in your config path on Linux? That would be very odd.

Comment: no it isnt, I just copied the structure it drew for windows, it indeed doesnt make sense. Ill look at viminfo again then, maybe ill get it to work then and can accept an answer here :)

Comment: Basically if you can get it to look at your vimrc file, you can get it to do any other configuration you want in arbitrary locations by modifying that vimrc.

Comment: yes it finds my vimrc but I cant seem to figure out how to get it to find the directories if I put them outside `vimfiles`

Comment: Did you add the set viminfo command to your vimrc? to clarify, viminfo is a folder and your bundle plugins etc should be subfolders inside it. If you have any plugins that are configured make sure any paths called out in vimrc are correct.

Comment: I tried `set viminfo=$VIM` but that isnt valid syntax, vim told me on startup. I want to set it to the `$VIM`dir though, if I understand it correctly

Comment: I just saw the edit, I guess ill try to build it myself and if I cant get it to work ill use the 'workaround'

Comment: If you are still trying to make this work, post your relevant config files and paths to a pastebin type site and provide a link. Some additional eyes on it might catch something.  If you are rebuilding from src and its not working you can provide the code changes in the same manner. I'm curious how this ends/ ended.

Comment: I got it to work via `set runtimepath`, I think the biggest problem was me trying to word my problem. But now I can have the exact same folder structure on linux and wiindows (no additional `vimfiles`) which is very useful

Answer (score 0):

This is the directory structure you are supposed to have:

```
Linux                 Windows

$HOME                 %USERPROFILE%
 └─ .vim               └─ vimfiles
     ├─ after              ├─ after
     ├─ autoload           ├─ autoload
     ├─ colors             ├─ colors
     ...                   ...
```

The directory structure inside `.vim` and `vimfiles` is the same so you don't have to adjust anything.

Comment: But on windows, if I put the `vimrc` in `vimfiles` it wont load it while on inux it is in `.vim`

Comment: Update your Vim on Windows. The ability to do `vimfiles/vimrc` is a new-ish feature introduced late in 7.3's development cycle and officialized in 7.4.

Comment: I just tried it again (I have 7.4.x) and it didnt work. Maybe it is a bad idea to try to make vim into a portable program... Could that be the source of my problems?